# Errors in chrome://gpu after the latest mesa 21.0.3 update

Tags: google-chrome, mesa

**System: Xubuntu 20.04.3 LTS**

After the latest `mesa 21.0.3` update, the following errors appear 5 times in *chrome://gpu* every time **Chrome 94.0.4606.61** starts:

```
[4283:4283:0929/115416.341346:WARNING:angle_platform_impl.cc(49)] : ProgramGL.cpp:989 (checkLinkStatus): Program link or binary loading failed with no info log.
[4283:4283:0929/115416.341620:ERROR:shared_context_state.cc(73)] : Skia shader compilation error ------------------------ Errors:
```

The last time this message had appeared, was on January 2021 and it was after a similar update. A Chrome update had fixed it back then.

Do we know anything about it this time?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **Chrome 94.0.4606.71** update fixed it.